# What does it mean "having a bit of a fall"?

Tags: meaning

Recently I came across this sentence from a native speaker. 
Looking for a correct meaning of this.

Comment: Would normally mean tripping and falling, without severe injury.  Could be used figuratively.

Comment: It could mean he suffered some financial loss. Please provide context.

Comment: In Britain, old people are often said to 'have a fall'.

Comment: In Britain, we often use understatement. "I'm having a bit of a fall" is code for "I'm in deep trouble."

Comment: If it is unseasonably cool in October, I might say, "My, aren't we having a bit of a Fall." :-) (That's a joke, @Mandy.)